# ASPNET Core with OpenId Connect and Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I've got an ASP.NET Core app running on an Azure Website. The site has been set up to authenticate using Azure AD as per this [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore)

We've been testing the site with a group of users and initially, they can access the site. After about 24 hours when they try to access the website goes into a loop between **/signin-oidc** on my site and the https://login.microsoftonline.com auth endpoint and then crashes with a 502.3 bad gateway.

Not sure if it's related but I'm also seeing this in the logs

> Authorization failed for user: (null).

This is happening on two Azure Websites (staging and production), but I'm not able to replicate it on my laptop running locally.

This is the code I'm using in StartUp.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = azureAdOptions.ClientId;

    var scopes = new List<string>
    {
        "openid,",
        "email",
        "profile,",
        "offline_access",
        "user_impersonation",
        "User.Read",
        "Mail.Read",
        "Mail.Send",
        "Directory.Read",
        "User.ReadBasic.All",
        "Calendars.ReadWrite",
        "Sites.ReadWrite.All"
    };

    foreach (var scope in scopes)
    {
        options.Scope.Add(scope);
    }

    options.Resource = graphOptions.ResourceId;
    options.Authority = $"{azureAdOptions.AadInstance}{azureAdOptions.Tenant}";
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = azureAdOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri;
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
        {
            var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
            var identifier = context.Principal.GetObjectIdentifierValue();
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var authProvider = provider.GetService<IInSiteAuthProvider>();

            var result = await authProvider.GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(identifier, code);

            if (result == null)
            {
                context.Fail("couldn't get auth code");
            }
            else
            {
                context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
            }
        }
    };
}).AddCookie();
```

Comment: Just wondering if you've tried the workaround referenced at the bottom of this [issue report](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6806).

Comment: @huysmania Thanks, I'll give that a go

Comment: One day sounds awfully specific.. Your org doesn't by any chance require MFA for users with a checkbox that remembers it for one day? Just a thought since I had an issue with that today where the MFA never popped up but then I was unable to get a token because "interaction is required".

Comment: But then Azure AD would return you an error when you try to exchange the authorization code. Do you have any logging for that?

Comment: They don't have MFA enabled. The only thing I can think of is the cookie has expired and it's try to authorise from that and that's what's causing the problem

Comment: @huysmania the 24 hour thing maybe a red herring. Testing the site on my own it all works OK. As soon as more users start accessing it it goes into this loop.